# Converting numerical bar (column) graph axis to Text Axis VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi so I wrote this today to create a bar graph based on some data in my sheet but it is treating my column of months as numbers (instead labeling the x axis with 1-12). Is there a way to manipulate it to take the column as text and therefore make the axis "January, February, Etc."

This could also apply to names of binned data I suppose.

```
'Create Range for Y
   Dim rng1Y As Range, rng2Y As Range
   Dim Y_Range As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")
Set rng1Y = .Cells(1, A + 7)

' Prevents Crashing if no data is in column
    If Cells(1, A + 7) = "" Then

    Else

    Set rng2Y = .Cells(1, A + 7).End(xlDown)

    Set Y_Range = .Range(rng1Y.Address & ":" & rng2Y.Address)
    Y_Range.Select

    End If


'Adds a second Series if needed
If Cells(2, A + 8) = "" Then

Else

 'Create Range for X
    Dim rng1X As Range, rng2X As Range
    Dim X_Range As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")
Set rng1X = .Cells(1, A + 8)

'prevents crashing if no data is in column
If Cells(2, A + 8) = "" Then

Else

Set rng2X = .Cells(1, A + 8).End(xlDown)

Set X_Range = .Range(rng1X.Address & ":" & rng2X.Address)
X_Range.Select

End If


 ' Creates full range for Bar graph
Set Total_Range = .Range(Y_Range.Address & ":" & X_Range.Address)

Total_Range.Select

End With
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------

'Build chart

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart

Set chrt = Nothing
Set Sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graphs")
Set chrt = Sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With chrt


    'Titles
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Cells(i + 12, 2).Value
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Title Here X"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Title here Y"
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .HasLegend = True

    End With
End If

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You may need to completely change the way you create your chart, as you can't programatically switch x and y values (I don't *think*). Basically you're trying to switch your Y and X values, right?

Comment: Not really switch but instead treat the data differently. It want to treat data that is in words, as numbers.  It still places it on the correct axis, but rather than showing in months (Jan. Feb. Mar.) it shows it as number where (Jan.=1 Feb.=2 Mar.=3 etc.)